# Carl Faith example's

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, injective-module

I study the properties of the ring $R$ in the following example, but I don't know if $R$ is semisimple or not.

let $D$ be a field, $U$ an infinite dimension vector space over $D$, set $T=End(U)$, $K=soc(T)$ and let $R$ be the subring of $T$ generated by $K$ and the scalar transformation $1d$, for $d \in D$ .

This example was presented for the first time by C. Faith in Lectures on Injective Modules and Quotient Rings.

Comment: Why the [commutative-algebra] tag? Don't you find $R$ pretty obviously not commutative?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you're talking about the right socle or left, but I think it isn't important for answering the question at hand, so I pick the right hand side.

If you represent $T$ with row finite (or column finite) matrices, then each row contains a copy of $U_T$, which is a simple $T$ module and is therefore contained in $soc(T_T)$. There are infinitely many rows, though, so you can easily build an infinite descending chain (and an infinite ascending chain) of submodules of $soc(T_T)$ by "stacking" these submodules.

This can't occur in a semisimple ring because of the ACC and DCC on right ideals.

Comment: The left socle and the right socle are equal; they consist of the endomorphisms with finite dimensional image.

Comment: @egreg I only mentioned the nonspecificity to sensitize the poster to avoiding ambiguity. That is why I wrote "it is not important for the question at hand."

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for answering. I wonder if we can show that R isn't semisimple by using the Loewy length of R, the Loewy length of R is 2 but I don't have any idea about the Loewy length of a semisimple ring.

Comment: @MManhal the Lowry length of a semisimple ring is clearly $1$. By definition, $soc(R_R)=R$, so the series ends after one iteration

Comment: Sorry loewy typo while autocorrect :(

Comment: @rschwieb can we say that R isn't semisimple since the loewy length of R is 2 ?

Comment: @MManhal sure: I thought that was your point.